# controller caching via custom routes

Tags: caching, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hey there,
my goal is to get either a generated or a cached version of a page using custom routes.

To do so I created a second custom route targeting the same controller.

```
Router::connect('/get/*', array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction'));
Router::connect('/getnocache/*', array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction'));
```

The problem by doing so is, that the $cacheAction is ignoring this (caching nothing):

```
var $cacheAction = array(
    'get/*' => '1 hour'
);
```

When using $cacheAction normally all requests get cached:

```
var $cacheAction = '1 hour';
```

Am I'm missing something or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad practice to create two different links for the same controller/action/params information. You won't run into problems when requesting a page, but if you use CakePHP to create a link it'll always use the first match, so you always get a /get/* url.

However, there is a solution. You can simply specify more items in the second parameter:

```
Router::connect('/get/*', array(
    'controller' => 'mycontroller', 
    'action' => 'myaction', 'useCache' => true
));

Router::connect('/getnocache/*', array(
    'controller' => 'mycontroller', 
    'action' => 'myaction', 'useCache' => false
));
```

Based on the extra parameter you can easily decide whether or not to cache the request. I'm not sure exactly how you can get access to that parameter in the controller (it's been a while since I last used CakePHP), but I do know that it's possible. It's probably something like `$this->params['useCache']` in the controller.

Comment: To complete your answer the parameter is accessed via $this->cacheAction = [MIXED];